# How to change various settings of wireless connection in Android

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, settings

Short story: I upgraded my phone to Kitkat and can't get to the Internet using wifi. After a few check I detected Android had wrong setting: my wifi router use AES, not TKIP (WPA2,802.11n mode)

I find it nowhere to change the setting, is there anywhere to set it? Google ain't my friend this time :(

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know for Kitkat (cannot check, have none). But with ICS and up, in the list of networks you can long-press a network's entry to edit it, and there have an "advanced" button to reveal some more details (usually IP, gateway, and the like). Not sure whether it has the details you require there – and I'm not sure [the only tools I know for that](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_config) still work with Kitkat. Might be worth taking a look at them, though.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) Android default setting definitely can't switch from TKIP to AES, only static IP, proxy things :(

Comment: Have your checked some apps from the link of my previous comment? Are they capable of doing what you need?

Comment: Glad to read you've found a solution! May I suggest you put that as an answer and then "accept" it (clicking the check-mark next to it), so others can identify it as solved? It's perfectly fine to answer your own question on SE :) // Btw: If you don't have a device still bound to "802.11b" (11MBit, pretty old stuff), you might wish to leave that off if possible (i.e. use "gn mixed"). Dropping that old "compatibility mode" will gain you some speed on g/n ;)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion Izzy : )  Will do as you recommend !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get it works by change the router wireless mode from `802.11n only` to `bgn mixed`, or better option like Izzy suggests `gn mixed`

Comment: @HasH_BrowN As it is his own: wasn't there a 2-days delay before he can?

Comment: Didn't think about that.